# XCode how to know SDK Version Used to create older project

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any way to find which SDK used to create the xcode project. Actually I have source code for the project but not aware which SDK used to create that project. The problem right now I am facing is using the latest SDK the xcode shows some reference error with an external library which is linked by the project. And these libraries are compiled at the time of the project created.

And I am thinking like, if I use the same SDK which is used to create the project at first time,  the linking problem will not happen, and I can start working  with the project. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks and regards,

Haris

Comment: You need to move forward. Get it to work with the latest tools. Update your question to be about fixing the issues.

Comment: Actually If I moves like that, may be I have to build the ffmpeg library as the dependency, and I don’t have much time.

Comment: He may have an external library which does not have a link slice for the latest architectures.  In that case, he should adjust the build settings to reflect only what he can build for.